# Hide messages when angular form is touched

Tags: angular, forms, validation

I am using Angular 6 and I have the following form

```
 <form  (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit(myForm)" #myForm="ngForm">    
   first name <input type="text" autofocus id="firstname" required [(ngModel)]="firstname" name="firstname" #firstnameValidityMsg="ngModel"  >
   <div *ngIf="firstnameValidityMsg.invalid && (firstnameValidityMsg.dirty || firstnameValidityMsg.touched)" >
       <div *ngIf="firstnameValidityMsg.errors.required"> first name is required </div>
    </div>    
   <button type="submit" [disabled]="!myForm.form.valid">Submit</button>    
   <div *ngIf="formSuccess && myForm.touched && myForm.dirty"> {{formSuccessMessage}} </div>      
</form>
```

My component is

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ProfileService } from '../../services/profile.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile', templateUrl: './profile.component.html',  
     styleUrls: ['./profile.component.css']
})

export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {
  firstname:String;
  formSuccess:boolean=false;
  formSuccessMessage:String;

  constructor( private profileService: ProfileService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.profileService.getProfile().subscribe((data) =>{
      if(data.success){
        this.firstname = data.firstname;
    })
  }

  onFormSubmit(myForm:any){
    const user = {
      firstname:this.firstname
    }
    this.profileService.saveProfile(user).subscribe((data) =>{
      if(data.success){
        this.formSuccessMessage = data.msg;
        this.formSuccess = true;
      }
      else{console.log('server doesn't like you');}
    })
  }    
}
```

When the page loads, I get some data to fill the form. For the form submission, I change `formSuccessMessage` and `accountsuccess` to reflect success  and show the message in the form.

**The problem**

I want to show the success message after the Submit is hit and then hide the success message after the form is touched. This will go on for any future submit or touch

The `<div *ngIf="formSuccess && myForm.touched && myForm.dirty"> {{formSuccessMessage}} </div>` is not capable of doing this. It does show  the message the first time and thats it. It never hides the message when the form is touched, to re-show it in a future submit. I guess since the form has always data in it and it is never reset, this will not work. I cannot find any other combination to make it work. At some point, after the first submit, all the states stay the same, you can check by using.

```
  <p>myForm.dirty - {{myForm.dirty}}</p>
  <p>myForm.pristine - {{myForm.pristine}}</p>
  <p>myForm.untouched - {{myForm.untouched}}</p>
  <p>myForm.touched - {{myForm.touched}}</p>
  <p>formSuccess - {{formSuccess}}</p>
```

How to fix this?

Thank you

Comment: Add you'r code to [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com) please.

Comment: I dont have an account there. Is jsfiddle ok ?

Comment: Its ok add to jsfiddle . but you don't need to login into stackblitz.

Comment: @Arash Hi again. [This link](https://angular-jc9ipg.stackblitz.io/) will do?

Comment: No , please generate a link with source. i need to see you'r source to debug it.

Comment: Ah, you are right, I am sorry. Here s the [source](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jc9ipg)

Comment: @Arash Completely ignore `profile.component.html` and `profile.component.ts`  I though I deleted them. Check `app.component.ts`, `app.component.html` and `profile.service.ts`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have a boolean, for example `isSubmitted` and then subscribe to `valueChanges` of `NgForm` directive, then look for whenever value changes, set `isSubmitted` flag to false. Then of course switch the flag to `true` when form is submitted... import `NgForm` and `ViewChild` to referece the form. You need to set the `valueChanges` in `AfterViewInit`, because that is when the DOM elements are available...

```ts
@ViewChild('myForm') myF: NgForm;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.myF.valueChanges.subscribe((data) => {
    this.formSuccessMessage = '';
    this.isSubmitted = false;
  });
}
```

Then in your template you would have...

```html
<div *ngIf="formSuccessMessage && isSubmitted"> {{formSuccessMessage}} </div>
```

And as mentioned, switch the `isSubmitted` to true when submitting your form.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-benwpm?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear! :) Have a nice day and happy coding!